# Can't get value from slide in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I have a simple slider UI and I want to get the value as it changes dynamically, but I can't seem to make it work. I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( "#slider" ).slider({
            value:0,
            min: 0,
            max: 24,
            step: 1,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
              $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value + " hrs");
            }
        });
        $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) + " hrs" );
    });
  });
</script>
```

and...

```
<p>
<label for="amount">Time (1hr increments):</label>
<input type="text" id="amount" />
</p>
    <div id="slider"></div>
```

And to check I have it working I am using:

```
$("#slider").change(function() {
   alert($("#slider").val());
});
```

But no joy. Sorry if I am being overly dumb! Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `$("#slider").val()` gives you the html `value` attribute, like in `<div id="slider" value="text">`, which is intended for input fields.

Comment: Seems to working just fine in my [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JDauH/3/) ??

Comment: Ok, I understand that now. How should I grab the actual value then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead `change()` method:

```
$("#slider").bind("slidechange", function(event, ui) {
    alert(ui.value);
});
```

Comment: Hey, that's great! The only thing is that the value is alerted when the slider stops moving and the click is released. Is this just an artefact of the alert? The intended operation for this is to dynamically update a Maps API so ideally I want it to continue updating the value as the slider moves. Will this work?

Comment: So you need the event `slide` instead `slidechange`. But you already have this event to populate your input.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with the jQuery 'on' method?

```
$('#slider').on('change', function() {
   alert($('#slider').val());
});
```